# Migrate TrafficMgr profiles to new Azure portal

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I have a number of Traffic Manager profiles that were setup 4 years ago. I'd like to get them migrated to the ARM approach so I can see and manage them in the new Azure portal.

Is there any way to migrate them? I see that I could create new ones in the new Portal that mirror the existing ones (though with slightly different names to get a unique url) and then remap my CNAME entries. But this is cumbersome and seems error prone. Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working to integrate our ARM/ASM experiences.  Once that is done, your existing profiles will show up in the new portal with no further action on your part.

In the meantime, as you point out, you can re-create the profiles via the new Portal, but will have to use a different DNS name, requiring a CNAME change.

The only other option would be to delete the old profile and then re-create via ARM, using the same DNS name.  Obviously, DNS names will not resolve correctly during the transition.  Changes in Traffic Manager take only a few seconds to be reflected in our name servers, so if you were to automate this approach e.g. using PowerShell or CLI, the downtime would be minimal and in many cases clients would not notice due to DNS caching.

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure Traffic Manager